# Why do we work on homogeneous Besov/Triebel-Lizorkin spaces?

Tags: schwartz-distributions, function-spaces, besov-spaces

This question is mainly for understanding the history behind homogeneous spaces.

There is extensive literature on Besov and Triebel-Lizorkin spaces. For instance, see the standard textbook:

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-16830-7

One thing that I never really understood is **why do we use homogeneous spaces instead of non-homogeneous ones ?**.

Is there some original motivation as to why these spaces were used ?